# Why doesn't custom SwiftUI view react to state changes

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, uikit

I've had this issue with many different custom views in SwiftUI, so why does code such as

```swift
struct HeaderText: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .font(.custom("Gilroy-SemiBold", size: 20))
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

not update automatically when `text` or `color` changes.  For instance, if I had a view such as

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "Hello"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeaderText(text: self.text, color: .black)
            Button("Change Text") {
                self.text = "Goodbye"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would have expected for the view to update with the new text, but it doesn't.  I know you can accomplish this with `@Binding`, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution, similar to how `Text` works.  I'm just using these views and `structs` as an example, so I'm aware these may not be best practices in general.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI is a functional programming thing. `Struct`s are value type( not reference type). Structs are normally immutable.

You can simply have `let`s in your sub view struct.

**Why** - SwiftUI re-create your views when `@State` changes instead of modifying it. This is done by calling the `body` again.

```swift
    struct HeaderText: View {
        let  text: String //<= here
        let  color: Color //<- here
        
        var body: some View {
            Text(text)
                .font(.custom("Gilroy-SemiBold", size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(color)
        }
    }
```

**Why does not** the code which is in the question work ,

It is because those state variables initialise with the given value (inside parent view ) as well as non of changes done to `@state` which is inside child view (HeaderText) **Because** `@State` can be change inside within the view itself.